# Magento 2: How is it possible to call a static block in category description?

Tags: magento2, category, static-block, category-description

is it possible to call **static blocks** in the **category description** of **magento 2**?

I don´t want to use the "Add CMS Block" DropDown under the description field.

It is necessary to call the blocks in the description field.

I would like to call blocks like sliders: `{{revslider alias="fullslider-en"}}`

or product lists:

```
{{block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\ProductList\Featured" template="product/list.phtml" category_id="13"}}
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance
Andi

Answer (score 2):

**Override View.php block**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Category/View.php

Add class **\Zend_Filter_Interface** in your block to filter output to html

```
...
protected $templateProcess;
...

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Zend_Filter_Interface $templateProcess
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->templateProcess = $templateProcess;
    ...
}

public function filterOutputHtml($string) 
{
    return $this->templateProcess->filter($string);

}
```

In your **di.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Block\Category\View">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="templateProcessor" xsi:type="object">Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Now call filterOutputHtml() to description.phtml

**Override description.phtml to your theme**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/description.phtml

```
<?php 

//Get category description
$_description = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription();

//Convert block {{ }} to html
<?php echo $block->filterOutputHtml($_description);
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Zend_Filter_Interface

Comment: @KetanBorada You need to add di.xml. Please check my updated answer

Comment: i'm still getting same error are you sure this is right? http://prntscr.com/ko585c

Comment: can you show by objectmanager?

Comment: @PrincePatel I am also working same task can you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330082/57334

Answer (score 0):

You need to override core functionality to show widget options then you can insert static block using widget interface.

**Create/Edit your di.xml and define a preference:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for='Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Helper\Form\Wysiwyg\Content' type='[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Helper\Form\Wysiwyg\ContentRewrite'/>
</config>
```

File **Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Helper\Form\Wysiwyg\Content**

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        [
            'data' => ['id' => 'wysiwyg_edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post'],
        ]
    );

    $config['document_base_url'] = $this->getData('store_media_url');
    $config['store_id'] = $this->getData('store_id');
    $config['add_variables'] = false;
    $config['add_widgets'] = true; // change this from false to true
    $config['add_directives'] = true;
    $config['use_container'] = true;
    $config['container_class'] = 'hor-scroll';

    $form->addField(
        $this->getData('editor_element_id'),
        'editor',
        [
            'name' => 'content',
            'style' => 'width:725px;height:460px',
            'required' => true,
            'force_load' => true,
            'config' => $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig($config)
        ]
    );
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

You may also need to override the block and view file for templateProcess.